# How do I use Apache mod_rewrite rewritecond with POST parameters?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-security

I know I can inspect GET query string parameters in rewritecond as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/somepath/somepath
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} try=3
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^/somepath/somepath(.*) /otherpath/otherpath?name=%1 [R]
```

How do I inspect POST parameters that are in the request body?  I hear mod_security can do it, but I'm not finding any examples of how I'd use mod_security in conjunction with mod_rewrite like the above example.

I intend to use something like this to handle POSTs:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/somepath/somepath
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^/somepath/somepath(.*) /otherpath/otherpath [PT]
```

...except that I need a RewriteCond that inspects the POST parameters to see if "try=3".

Can modsecurity inspect the request body and load the result of that inspection in an environment variable?  that would work...

Comment: I don't suppose you ever got this figured out, did you?  I am facing a very similar situation.

Comment: No solution using Apache HTTP server.  In my case, Apache is a reverse proxy to a back end weblogic server.  I ended up writing a java servlet hosted in weblogic to handle redirects for POSTs.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up needing to do a similar thing.  Built a little node.js app as my reverse proxy.  Not as clean as I would have liked it, but it works.

Answer (score 5):

You can't inspect the request body using mod_rewrite.

You may have to rewrite POST requests to a script if that's something that you can do. Browser's aren't always going to resend POST data if you redirect them.

Comment: Thanks Jon.  I've updated my question showing how I intend to handle POSTs - using PT rather than R.